# How can I use jQuery to tally up the total count of the values in my columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Created column should have "7" for the Total row. The Redeemed column should have "6" for the total row. Sometimes, there will only be two months of rows or there could be ten rows. How can I total the values up and stick them in the last row of the table using jQuery?

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="DataGrid2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tbody><tr>
    <td>CreationDate</td><td>Created</td><td>Redeemed</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>August 2011</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>July 2011</td><td>1</td><td>0</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>June 2011</td><td>1</td><td>0</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Total</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

**Image:** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this one gets values for both columns...

```
var c2Total = 0;
var c3Total = 0;

$("tr").find("td").each(function(){
    var curVal = parseInt($(this).text());

    if(!isNaN(curVal)){
        if($(this).index() == 1){
           c2Total += parseInt($(this).text());
        }
        else if($(this).index() == 2){
           c3Total += parseInt($(this).text());
        }
    }

});
$("#DataGrid2 tr:last td:eq(1)").text(c2Total );
$("#DataGrid2 tr:last td:eq(2)").text(c3Total );
```

You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Broham/Rtm8p/2/

Comment: This works but only gets the created column. How can I get the redeemed total as well?

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution, but should support an infinite number of columns without any further editing:

```
$(function() {
    var totals = [];
    $("#DataGrid2 tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:gt(0)").each(function(){
            var val = (parseInt($(this).text()) || 0);
            totals[$(this).index() - 1] = ((totals[$(this).index() - 1]) ? totals[$(this).index() - 1] + val : val);
        });             
    });

    for(var i = 0; i < totals.length; i++) {
        $("#DataGrid2 tr:last td:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").text(totals[i]); 
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For each column `i`, loop through each row of the table (i.e. each `<tr>`), keeping track of a running sum for the `i`th `<td>` in that row.

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = 0;

$('#DataGrid2 td:nth-child(3)').each(function(){
    total += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
});

$('#DataGrid2 td:last').text(total);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WPfWE/1/

Comment: This worked, but only totaled up the redeemed column. The created column is blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have a JQuery plugin, **[Sumtr](https://github.com/DLarsen/jquery-sumtr)**, which does summation on an arbitrary table.  By default, it assumes you want to sum rows in the `<tbody>` for cells with the `.sum` class.  It spits the results into rows with the `.summary` class.

The defaults are easily configurable.

http://jsfiddle.net/vaNZB/.